# Struct inheritance without parent struct duplication

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

In my code I have two almost identical structs, which I have here simplified:

```cpp
struct foo {
    struct bar {
        int b;
    } a;
};

struct foo2 {
    struct qux {
        int b;
        int c;
    } a;
};
```

(The only difference here is that qux has a member `c` while bar does not.)

My question is, **Is there a way to let qux inherit from bar, without having to create two foo?** This can easily be done with classes, but I want to know if it can be achieved with structs. In my imagination it would look something like this:

```cpp
struct bar {
    int b;
};

struct qux : bar {
    int c;
};

struct foo {
    bar_or_qux a;
};
```

Comment: Suppose you somehow managed to achieve what you want. How do you plan to use this `foo`? When you then write `foo f;`, should it mean foo-with-c or foo-without-c?

Comment: Luckily, `struct`s in C++ support all the features that `class`es do, so whatever `class` solution you're thinking of will work equally well for a `struct`.

Comment: Do not use inheritance as a means to reduce code writing.  Only if it makes logical sense to inherit one class from another should you do this.  If a `bar` and a `qux` are totally different in terms of their purpose in your program, then inheritance shouldn't be used.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve? Why is there a `foo` and `foo2`? Are you yet to discover polymorphism? `struct foo { std::unique_ptr<bar> a; };` Are you yet to discover templates? `template <typename T> struct foo { T a; };`.

Comment: @StephenNewell See my comment on Ricardo Silvia's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the snippet posted in a comment to Ricardo's answer.

```
struct bar {
    int b;
};

struct qux : bar {
    int c;
};

struct foo {
    bar a;
};

int main() {
    qux q;
    foo f;
    f.a = q;
    f.a.b = 7;
    // f.a.c = 3;
}
```

This sort of thing might work in Python or JavaScript but this is C++. Assigning a `qux` to a `bar` doesn't magically turn the `bar` into a `qux`. This `f.a = q` is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). I'm not sure exactly what you want but I'm gonna make a few guesses and maybe I'll stumble upon it.

---

You could use templates. This would mean that you can have a "foo with a qux" type and a "foo with a bar" type.

```
struct bar {
    int b;
};

struct qux : bar {
    int c;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    T a;
};

int main() {
    qux q;
    foo<qux> f;
    f.a = q;
    f.a.b = 7;
    f.a.c = 3;
}
```

---

You could use polymorphism. This would mean that you can have a single `foo` type that can store a subclass of `bar` (e.g. `qux`).

```
#include <memory>

struct bar {
    int b;

    virtual void setC(int) = 0;
};

struct qux : bar {
    int c;

    void setC(const int value) override {
        c = value;
    }
};

struct foo {
    std::unique_ptr<bar> a;
};

int main() {
    qux q;
    foo f;
    f.a = std::make_unique<qux>(q);
    f.a->b = 7;
    f.a->setC(3);
}
```

---

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance with structs in the same way as classes.

Structs in C++ have all the same capabilities as classes, with the only differential being that their members (declarations) and bases (inheritance) are public by default, while for classes, they're private by default.

Comment: Turns out my assumption was incorrect, you can't do this with classes: https://pastebin.com/YYBRMZQL

Comment: ah, for that you need to use either raw pointers, references, or smart pointers since you can't do polymorphism with simple values